# Sugar daddy asked me to send $29 to his account manager's PayPal

Tags: scams, paypal, sugar-daddy

This is the first time I've used a sugar daddy site and I have little idea what I'm doing. I was smart enough to set up a PayPal account so he wouldn't have any of my personal information. He set an amount at which he would send, assuming I "passed his tests". Then he asked me to start by sending $29 to his account manager's PayPal so he would have my information. Am I right to think this is a scam?

Comment: That potential duplicate is slightly different, but the end result is the same. If someone wants to give you money they can do so through legitimate channels and without you paying them. The whole point is that their money gets traded for "sugar" which can mean different things, but in no legitimate scenario would they need your money first.

Comment: How many people do you think are out there who want to send you money for no reason? Compared with how many people who see a site full of naive young people and try to scam them?

Comment: Any scheme where you have to pay money  to get money, **is always an advance-fee scam** (or Nigerian Prince/lottery scam).   You won't get money. You'll get a cock and bull story of why you need to pay another fee, around 2.5x the original amount (e.g. $75-ish).  After that, another ($200-250). Then another in the $600 neighborhood.  Then another $1500-ish.  $4000. $10,000.  They'll take it to the moon if you keep falling for it.

Comment: I don’t know too much about these “sugar daddy” or “sugar mommy” things, but I know for sure that you are not the one who is supposed to pay.

Answer (score 15):

You said that this individual was going to test you, and then...

> asked me to start by sending $29 to his account managers payapl so he would have my information, am right to think this is a scam?

Regardless of if this is a scam or not (although it almost certainly is), that's not at all how PayPal works. If someone wants to send you money, all they need to know is the email address you have registered with PayPal. They can then simply go on PayPal themselves, and send you money. **They do not need you to send them money first.**

That should set off a red flag. If this person doesn't need you to send them money first, then why are they asking you to do so? It doesn't make any sense, and there is no good reason for them to ask you for $29. Think of it this way: if you were walking down the street, and a stranger came up to you and said, "I want to give you money, but first give me $29" you'd probably just say no and walk away (or even call the police, because this basically sounds like a friendly way to mug someone).

Comment: I see this got a downvote before I even had time to scroll back to the top of the page. Would the downvoter care to provide any feedback in terms of opportunities to improve this answer? I'd love to be able to learn why this was so clearly identifiable as a poor quality answer.

Comment: @duizum probably someone from SO or IPS showing you love, the only way you know how.

Comment: Drive by downvotes are a fact of life, I get that - the thing that surprised me in this case was that it was literally within seconds of hitting the submit button. The voter couldn't possibly have even read past the first sentence, much less taken the time to mentally process the content of the answer.

Comment: They may have been working on the Stack Exchange principle that if you answer a bad question, then not only should the question be downvoted, but the answer should too.  I think that's a stupid principle, myself.